# Python - REST API -- slow data loading to SQL

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, python-requests, pyodbc, rest

Below code "tries" to get data using a REST API and inserts data into SQL Server. The code works, but performance is too slow. Inserting 5K lines took a bit more than 30 min and there are around 250K lines more to insert.

Can you please take a look at the script and let me know if you can optimize the script to improve performance? Thank you for your support.

```
import requests, pandas, pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
date_n = datetime.now()

server = XXXXXXXXXX
database = XXXXXXXX
username_sql = XXXXXXXXXXXX
password_sql = XXXXXXXXXX

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' 
       + database + ';UID=' + username_sql + ';PWD=' + password_sql)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
truncate_table = """Truncate Table XXXXXXXXXX”””
cursor.execute(truncate_table)
cnxn.commit()

insert_query = """INSERT INTO xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ([lastnum],[name],[status],[status2], 
               [location],[date_n],[manuf],[number],[created],[BOOL],[system],[environment], 
               [owner]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"""

username = XXXXXXXXX
password = XXXXXXXX
new_results = True
base = 0

while new_results:
    url = "https//XXXXXXXXXXXXXoffset=" + str(base) + "XXXXXXXXLimit=5000&XXXXXXXXXXX"
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
    jsonresponse = response.json() 
    v = pandas.DataFrame(jsonresponse['result'])
    for index, row in v.iterrows():
        values = (
        row[0], row[5], row[2], row[10], row[7], date, row[11], row[8], row[3], row[1], 
        row[6], row[4], row[9])
        cursor.execute(insert_query, values)
        cnxn.commit()
    base = base + 5000
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: I don't know Python but you're inserting your rows 1-at-a-time in a loop. This would be slow in t-sql let alone factoring in external network round-trips on each insert. If you want to insert data into SQL Server in a performant fashion, send your data over the wire in larger batches - possibly as serialized json or a datatable using a SQL table-type parameter.

Comment: Have you read up on [execute_many](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-params-with-fast_executemanyfalse-the-default) yet?

Comment: Than you.... I have changed the code from execute to executemany and performance for 5K lines decreased from 30 min to 15 min.,, I also added fast_executemany = true at first but performance was same with "true" , I removed fast_executemany afterwards since it works faster without it.

However I believe this is still slow - 5K lines 15 min- is there anything else you would recommend to speed it up ?

Comment: You could definitely wrap up the while loop into a function and run it with multi-threading to boost performance